# How can I test a dishwasher's water inlet valve?

Tags: dishwasher, valve

Our Bosch dish-washing machine (SGS 6902EU/07) is no longer filling in with water, displaying "F" on the led panel. Opening the side panel I see that no water is flowing in from the water mains. The dishwasher is using an [Aquastop](http://www.bosch-home.com/us/store/product/Aquastop/00299756) 's main water inlet valve: this is located at the water mains location, rather than inside the dishwasher.

To determine whether the problem is associated with the inlet valve or with the dishwasher, I measured the voltage across the inlet valve's terminals and it was 0V. I then considered the possibility that the inlet valve was short circuited, so I also measured the voltage with one terminal disconnected. The the dishwasher was turned on, this rose to 2.4V DC.  I think this is too low; a manufacturer of such valves [gives](http://www.akmueller.de/en/products/product-detail/13007-226-aquastop/) a 12-220V range in its specifications.

Any idea on what the voltage should actually be?  Any suggestions for testing the valve?

Comment: Bosch error codes seem to be "E1", "E2", etc; not just "F".

Comment: These are indeed the diagnostic codes. The "F" appears in the normal wash cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inlet valve's are normally the first to go, so I'd stop testing & order that new valve assembly. Other than that, turn off the circuit breaker or perform a reset & see if it's just a temporary fault that blocked it's operation.

Comment: Indeed, replacing the inlet valve assembly fixed the problem. After removing the valve, I was able to read on its housing that its operating voltage is 230V AC. Also, the valve does not open until 5-10 minutes into the washing cycle. These factors confused my initial diagnosis.

Comment: Fabulous! I'm glad it worked out & thank you for your question! Your question & the solution that worked will be a big help to others.